# Computing and viewing column outside model using MVVM

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, mvvm-light, computation

I need to solve following problem using C# MVVM. I'm using following model.
[image]

And one of my UserControls got following ListBox template.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding OrdersListViewViewModel.AllItems, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" SelectedItem="{Binding OrdersListViewViewModel.SelectedItem, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Background="White">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 0 0 0" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel  Margin="0,7,0,6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Width="25" Height="25" Margin="5 2 0 0" Source="{Binding OrdersListViewViewModel.OrderDeliveryStateImage, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="25,5,25,5"  Text="{Binding OrdersListViewViewModel.AllItems/Customer.CustomerName, FallbackValue=N/A, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" FontSize="20"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The list is showing all orders (customer names) loaded from database. Image which is beside the TextBlock I want to fill in with a picture. If all orderitems under the order have been delivered (**Delivered=1**) it should use picture1, otherwise picture2.

So I'm binding `ObservableCollection<Order>`. Model is generated from .tt using entity framework (db first) so it's bad idea to place computing directly into Order.cs class because of possible db updates.

My first idea was to use **MSSQL Computed** column but I think that's not a good aproach (there can be a lot of situations like this one in a solution) so model would be huge and complicated.

Second idea was to use a **converter** but it should be used for a simple tasks, not for a computation logic (which this is).

Third idea was to change `ObservableCollection<Order>` to `ObservableCollection<Tuple<string,Order>>` and somehow bind it to a view but....you know, that's a bad idea.

So my question is simple. How can I solve this issue (**where to place a computation logic** of this purpose) using a MVVM best practice.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a datatrigger, or figure it out in the view model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a googling around I've decided to create this solution. Maybe it will help to someone.
First I've created partial class of Order entity in order to separate files so when entity framework will update the Order entity, it will not overwrite my customizations.

Then I've created custom property which determine if the Order has been delivered. So computation logic still stays at the model.

```
  public partial class Order
    {
        public bool IsOrderDelivered
        {
            get
            {
                int orderDelivered = 1;
                foreach (var orderItem in this.OrderItems)
                {
                    orderDelivered = orderDelivered * orderItem.Delivered;
                }
                return orderDelivered == 1 ? true : false;
            }
        }

    }
```

Then I've created converter which just converts boolean to text which is why it exists and it's used the right way.

```
public class OrderStatusToImageConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (bool)value == true ? @"Skins\approved.png" : @"Skins\denied.png";
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

And created databinding on my new property in partial class together with converter.

```
       <StackPanel  Margin="0,7,0,6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Width="25" Height="25" Margin="5 2 0 0" Source="{Binding IsOrderDelivered, Converter={StaticResource OrderStatusToImageConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    <TextBlock Margin="25,5,25,5"  Text="{Binding Customer.CustomerName, FallbackValue=N/A, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="20"/>
       </StackPanel>
```

And finally the visual effect.

[image]